# How to get a value from dicitionary in c#

Tags: c#, dictionary

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<People> people = new List<People>(){
        new People(){FirstName = "aaa", LastName = "zzz", Age = 3, Location = "Berlin"},
        new People(){FirstName = "aaa", LastName = "yyy", Age = 6, Location = "Paris"},
        new People(){FirstName = "bbb", LastName = "zzz", Age = 5, Location = "Texas"},
        new People(){FirstName = "bbb", LastName = "yyy", Age = 4, Location = "Sydney"},
        new People(){FirstName = "ccc", LastName = "zzz", Age = 2, Location = "Berlin"},
        new People(){FirstName = "ccc", LastName = "yyy", Age = 3, Location = "New York"},
        new People(){FirstName = "aaa", LastName = "xxx", Age = 2, Location = "Dallas"},
        new People(){FirstName = "bbb", LastName = "www", Age = 6, Location = "DC"},
        new People(){FirstName = "ccc", LastName = "vvv", Age = 3, Location = "Detroit"},
        new People(){FirstName = "ddd", LastName = "uuu", Age = 5, Location = "Gotham"}
    };

    var dict = people
      .GroupBy(x => (x.FirstName, x.LastName))
      .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, 
                    x => x.ToList());

    /**
        how to get a value from dictionary when i just have first name.
        i want to get all value from dict where name = "aaa"
    **/
}

public class People
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public int Age {get; set;}
    public string Location {get; set;}      
}
```

is there a way to get a value from dictionary with just 1 key (example i just have name "aaa", and i want to get all people with Firstname "aaa"). i can get it with where but there is no point in using dictionary. should i used nested dictionary or there's other way ?

Comment: Because your key is a 2-tuple of first and last names, it's not possible with that dictionary. You have insufficient information to create the necessary hash to find the item. You'd need to create another dictionary keyed on just the first name.

Comment: If you only have the first name, why did you create a dictionary with both the first name and last name as keys?

Comment: You can do it -
```var filteredDictionary = dict.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.FirstName == "aaa").Select(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();```, but that's not very different from filtering a regular list - 
```var filteredList = people.Where(p => p.FirstName == "aaa").ToList();```

Comment: Ok get it, so i can't get a value from dictionary because i need to fill all the necessary key. so it's better to use nested dictionary. thanks

Comment: yeah @mcjmzn if i use where there is no point in create dictionary. thanks

Comment: If you want to get all the values, where _FirstName_ is something, then why create a dictionary with FirstName _and_ LastName? Why not create a dictionary with _just_ the FirstName as key? Probably, because "maybe" at some point you _do_ also have the LastName. Okay, in _that very specific_ case a nested dictionary might help. But if that condition can be variable, how about the situation, where you only have the _LastName_? Then a nested dictionary with FirstName first doesn't help at all. Why not have dictionaries (or better yet: Lookups) for the exact situation needed?

Comment: You can have any number of dictionaries/lookups. The additional memory space requirement should be neglible. It should be in the realm of `sizeof(Reference) * numberOfItems` per additional d/l. Of course _creating_ a d/l will take some time, so it only makes sense, if you look for the same property (combination) several times. And you want to make sure to create a specific d/l only once. So maybe keep a dictionary of d/l and create the ones you need "on demand" once and re-use them later.

Comment: FYI, unless a `class` is a collection type, it should be named singularlly - i.e. `Person` instead of `People`. Then a `List<Person>` might be called `people`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `.GroupBy(x => new {x.FirstName, x.LastName})`? Or am I just on too old of a language version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point using the dictionary, I'm not sure what you're trying to achive by using it? Why not just use the list as mcjmzn said?

```
List<people> peopleCohort = people.Where(p=> p.FirstName == "aaa").ToList();
```

Think you might be overthinking it.

Stu.

UPDATE:

Given the following test:

```
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("SELECT Name FROM [Responses_PersonalData]", con);
        con.Open();
        List<Person> listPeople = new List<Person>();
        Dictionary<string, Person> dicPeople = new Dictionary<string, Person>();
        using (con)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        //Only use data where we have firstname, surname, approx 49,000 names in db.
                        string[] name = reader["Name"].ToString().Trim().Split(' ');
                        if (name.Length == 2)
                        {
                            Person person = new Person() { Age = rand.Next(0, 100), FirstName = name[0], LastName = name[1], Location = name[1] };
                            listPeople.Add(person);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //Creates approx 100 million people exponentially.
        for (int i = 1; i < 12; i++)
            listPeople.AddRange(listPeople);

        //Group by firstname lastname tuple
        var tuppleDicPeople = listPeople
            .GroupBy(x => (x.FirstName, x.LastName))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                x => x.ToList());

        //Method 1
        List<Person> listPeopleCohortResults = listPeople.FindAll(p => p.FirstName == "Dean");
        //Method 2
        List<Person> dicPeopleCohortResults = tuppleDicPeople.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.FirstName == "Dean").SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();
```

Findings:

The group by operation is very expensive.

listPeople.FindAll(p => p.FirstName == "Dean"); => 1651ms, returns 32768 results.

List dicPeopleCohortResults = tuppleDicPeople.Where(kvp => kvp.Key.FirstName == "Dean").SelectMany(kvp => kvp.Value).ToList();  => **10ms**, returns 32768 results.

If you can afford the expense of the group by then your solution is optimal given the limited research I've done.

Stu.

Comment: This works great, if you look for _one_ specific FirstName _once_. But it doesn't scale well when you have a list of hundreds of thousands (n) of `people` and want to be able to search for a lot of different FirstNames (m). This is O(n*m). With a dedicated dictionary it would be O(1*m).

Comment: Where is your list coming from in the first place - a database?

Comment: That's for the OP to say. Yes, with a properly indexed DB, you would have other, better options. The OP describes a list that is created in-memory... granted, having hundreds of thousands of entries that way is a bit unrealistic. For the sake of argument, let's assume the `people` information is stored in a plain text file. Maybe a CSV.

Comment: yeah sure i can use list but my concern  is performance because my real problem have a million data and i think it's better using dictionary for lookup but i got a problem to get data when i just have 1 pair of key but the dictionary need 2 pair of key. thanks for your help @Stuie_M

Comment: Updated my response.